# AngularJS UI-Router handling url with DOT

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, angular-ui-router

I am trying to authenticate users using the google api, but the return data in the params contain a DOT within the token that breaks the server, it basically requests another page that isn't there if I remove the DOT it works perfectly fine.

Here is the example url

```
http://localhost:9000/developer/auth/google?code=4/ubXcE1qq84XFtsAwT00_BWkLKR9RldGk6zhBS8ZSiTw.El_qMeir0J0coiIBeO6P2m_ee_B7kwI
```

And here is the state handler

```
  .state('/developer/auth/google', {
    url: '/developer/auth/google?code',
    templateUrl: 'views/developer/auth/google.html',
    controller: 'DeveloperAuthGoogleCtrl',
    resolve: {
    code: function($stateParams) {
        return $stateParams.code;
      }
    }
  })
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue.

I fixed this changing the rewrite rule to the node server. Now I can use DOT on any param

Check this rewrite rule:

```
modRewrite(['!\\.html|\\.js|\\.svg|\\.css|\\.png$ /index.html [L]'])
```